# Android, NFC, documentation: confusion

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I'm working on an app that must be able to read NFC tags. I've spent a lot of time reading documentation, but in the end I'm a bit confused and need a little hint if what I'm planning to do is correct (and if it's possible).

My app must be capable of reading NFC tags in two different ways:

1 - User has to manually activate the reading each time he needs: he tap the "Read" button from the MainActivity UI and put the NFC near the device; this is the default working mode and cannot be disabled. I know that by using PendingIntent and IntentFilter to declare a new intent I will receive tags data in onNewIntent.

2 - App is closed; a tag is put near the device, Android launch my app and pass it the Intent with tag data. By putting intent filters into the manifest and using getIntent() in onCreate I receive data.

Now my doubts are:
- My NFC activity is not the MainActivity: so, is it possible to declare new intents filter anywhere (for using enableForegroundDispatch), or it's mandatory to declare them in the main?

- Where to declare my intent filters? I surely needs them into the manifest for the "app is closed" scenario, but what happens when I redeclare them in code for the other scenario?
- Users can enable the "app is closed" scenario, but still keep the app running; how can I make the two things work at the same time? For example...user is on home screen, so no call has been done to enableForegroundDispatch (or disableForegroundDispatch has been called at the end at the last reading). What happens when a tag is put near the device?

Thanks everybody, just in case :-)

Comment: Not sure if this fits in for you... https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html it has a receiver in it which can launch your app..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where to declare my intent filters?**

- For the app closed scenario: Declare them for the activity that should be launched by the NFC event.
- For the activity in foreground scenario: You declare that your activity should get priority over all manifest-registered NFC intent filters using enableForegroundDispatch (and/or enableReaderMode).

**I surely needs them into the manifest for the "app is closed" scenario, but what happens when I redeclare them in code for the other scenario?**

Both approaches are completely independent of each other. They provide different (but complementing) functionality. You can use a combination of both. Typically you would register for the events that should start your app/activity in the manifest and additionally register for the foreground dispatch to give your activity priority over all other activities while it is visible to the user.